# Create Sql DB with powershell searching for dacpac and naming db with Folder its located in

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, dacpac

I am trying to create databases in Sql Server by searching for *.dacpac files within a folder, For each .dacpac found I need to create a DB with the name of the Folder the .dacpac was found in.

Example

C:\Folder\ contains

- C:\Folder\Project1\mydatabase.dacpac
- C:\Folder\Project2\mydatabase.dacpac
- C:\Folder\Project3\mydatabase.dacpac

Script to create Db

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin"
$createDB = .\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"c:\Folder\Project1\mydatabase.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:"Project1" /TargetServerName:"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB"
```

I can get the Folder names to use as TargetDatabaseName with the following

```
 PS C:\> $FolderName = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder | select -ExpandProperty Name
    $FolderName
    Project1
    Project2
    Project3
```

I am trying to use a foreach loop to find the dacpac files and use them as the SourceFile and then lookup the FolderName to use as TargetDatabaseName

```
$FolderName = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder | select -ExpandProperty Name
$dacpacfile = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder -Recurse -Include *.dacpac
    foreach ($dacpac in $dacpacfile){
        $createDB = .\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$dacpacfile /TargetDatabaseName:$FolderName /TargetServerName:"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB"}
```

The Error received is:

> .\sqlpackage.exe : *** Could not load package from
>   'C:\Folder\Project1\mydatabase.dacpac
>   C:\Folder\Project2\mydatabase.dacpac
>   C:\Folder\Project3\mydatabase.dacpac'. At line:4 char:21
>   + ... $createDB = .\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$dacpacfile  ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (*** Could not l...tabase.dacpac'.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I expect I need to create two arrays and try step through them together however not able to get this right, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
$dacpacFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\project -Recurse -Include *.dacpac
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin"
foreach ($dacpacFile in $dacpacFiles)
{
    $dir = Split-Path $dacpacFile.Directory -Leaf
    $filePath = $dacpacFile.FullName
    $createDB = .\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$filePath /TargetDatabaseName:$dir /TargetServerName:"."
}
```